# Overload functional parameter for in-place modification or not

Tags: c++, function, reference, overloading

I am working on a binary search tree, where the order matters.

If a node/ nodes get modified, the tree need update to keep the order right.

What I want to do is overload the visiting methods, such as `preOrderTraversal`; so that it can distinguish whether the function will modify the nodes or not.

```
void preOrderTraversal(std::function<void(Type)> visit); // read only visit
```

and

```
void preOrderTraversal(std::function<void(Type &)> visit); // write visit, update needed afterwards
```

if the `std::function` passed in is value parameter typed, means a read only visit, so no need to update the tree; if `std::function` is reference typed, the tree will be modified, hence `update` method need to be called.

I know that I can mark `preOrderTraversal` method as `const` and non `const` overload. However, would it be clear if we know the function pass in can change tree node or not, and overload them.

```
template<typename Type>
class BinaryTree {
public:
    struct Node {
        Type data;
        Node* left{ nullptr };
        Node* right{ nullptr };
        Node(Type && value) : data{ std::move(value) } { }
        Node() = delete;
    };
    // ... omit unrealated parts ...

    // head, left leaf, right leaf
    // value type, tree will not be modified
    void preOrderTraversal(std::function<void(Type)> visit) {
        std::cout << "void preOrderTraversal(std::function<void(Type)>)" << std::endl;
        preorder_utility(visit);
    }
    // reference type, tree will be modified; so the tree need update order of nodes.
    void preOrderTraversal(std::function<void(Type&)> visit) {
        std::cout << "void preOrderTraversal(std::function<void(Type&)>)" << std::endl;
        preorder_utility(visit);
        update(); // update function to keep the tree in binary search tree order.
    }
private:
    template <typename Function>
    void preorder_utility(Function visit) {
        if( nullptr == root ) return;
        std::stack<Node*> stack;
        stack.push(root);
        while( !stack.empty() ) {
            auto node = stack.top();
            stack.pop();
            visit(node->data);
            if( node->right ) {
                stack.push(node->right);
            }
            if( node->left ) {
                stack.push(node->left);
            }
        }
    }
    Node* root{nullptr};
};
```

So that we can have visit function can modify the tree or not.

```
// just as an example, readonly can not change the tree,
// while write may change the tree
void readonly(double value) {
    // value inside tree will not change
    value += 10.0;
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}

void write(double & value) {
    // value inside tree will change
    value += 10.0;
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}
```

so

```
int main() {
    BinaryTree<double> btree;

    // ... working on the tree..., push, pop, etc.

    btree.preOrderTraversal(readonly);
    btree.preOrderTraversal(write);
}
```

[update]
It looks like if I make `readonly` take rvalue-reference, the code will compile and work.

```
 // this will call void preOrderTraversal(std::function<void(Type)> visit)
 // hence no update method will be called.
void readonly(double && value) {
    // value inside tree will not change
    value += 10.0;
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I fail to understand where Your problem is. What's your question?

Comment: The question is overload tree visit method for`readonly` funtion and `write` function. The code above can not compile.